# How to avoid inconsistent window.screenX values in full-screen Chrome on Windows 10

Tags: google-chrome, windows-10

I am noticing inconsistent coordinates for window.screenX in full-screen depending on whether my browser window was maximized or not before I enter full-screen mode (with F11)

Here's how I'm observing my measurements:

https://jsfiddle.net/m68tjtna/

```
setInterval(function () {
    document.documentElement.innerText = window.screenX + ', ' + window.screenY;
}, 30);
```

Here's what I do in Chrome on Windows 10:

I run the fiddle, then press F11 to go to full-screen. I get different results on whether the browser window was maximized or not before pressing F11.

Breaking it down into the two cases; first run the fiddle, then:

A) Start with non-maximized browser, press F11.  Shows expected results (0,0) on the primary monitor.
B) Start with maximized browser, press F11.  Shows unexpected results (8,8) on the primary monitor.

And to be clear about the terminology, there's a difference between *Full-Screen* (F11) and *Maximized* (traditional Windows operation accessible in a variety of ways, such as clicking the maximize button, or pressing Alt+Space, X, or Windows+UpArrow)

Can anyone else reproduce this weird inconsistency?

Is this a Chrome bug?  A Windows bug?  Expected or unexpected?

Whatever is happening, it makes window.screenX and window.screenY unusable for me.  So I need an explanation, workaround, or a fix.

Comment: It happens in Chrome for me too. It's probably a weird side-effect of how Windows does maximized windows combined with how screenX/Y are implemented in Chrome. Windows actually expands the edges of the maximized window beyond the size of the screen... it's hard to explain, but I've encountered it when working with custom window styles in C#/WPF. Interestingly, Firefox handles this the other way -- it gives (-8,-8) when maximized and (0,0) after hitting F11.